# Formula for calculating camera x y position to force 3d point to appear in center of screen

Tags: math, 3d

I need the formula for calculating the camera x y position which will force a given 3D point to appear in the center of the screen. In other words, the camera pans to move the point into the center, without changing FOV, rotation, or z co-ordinate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that the current camera position is `camPos` and its direction is `camDir`. Depending on your projection, there several options how the view ray for the screen center is calculated but most of the time it is just:

```
ray(t) = camPos + camDir * t
```

We don't want to change the position's z-coordinate. So calculating the parameter t to hit the target point `p` is quite simple (given the position had correct x and y coordinates):

```
t = (p.z - camPos.z) / camDir.z
```

We can calculate the current point at the screen center at the given depth by:

```
currentScreenCenter = camPos + camDir * t
```

In order to hit `p`, `camPos` has to be shifted by this difference:

```
camPos += (p - currentScreenCenter)
        = p - camPos - camDir * (p.z - camPos.z) / camDir.z
```